# Using webclient in a method

Tags: c#, webclient, windows-phone-7

I'm looking into how i can create a webclient method that i can reuse in my code. Now the below code would call client_DownloadStringCompleted and i would have to deal with the returned data there, but i'd like to do it in the request method so i can return it.

```
private string request(string json, string url) {

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url);

}
```

Comment: is that better? and please there's no need to be rude.

Comment: no, it's not better. And I am not rude. I am just trying to help.

Comment: then please don't bother replying to this question if you think that's not being rude.... Usually if someone asked me for help i certainly wouldnt reply with that attitude.

Comment: I am not replying, as you can see. I am simply commenting for your own good. Because I thought that at its present form your question risks to stay into oblivion. So I thought it might be a good idea to ask you to improve it. Sorry if I am wrong. Ignore me in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebClient - wait until file has downloaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727928/webclient-wait-until-file-has-downloaded)

Answer (score 2):

The WebClient call is asynchronous, and it's that for a reason. The reason is usually to not block the UI thread during the wait time when the call has been initiated and the result has come back through the wire.

I think you are making a design mistake by enforcing an old school blocking call.

See my response in this question for solutions. [WebClient - wait until file has downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727928/webclient-wait-until-file-has-downloaded)

Answer (score 0):

As the web request is performed asynchronously there isn't an easy way to have that method block and only return when (if?) the response is received. (There is a way to do this but it is recommended against for perf, usability and maintainability reasons.)

Instead you should write code that is designed to be run asynchronously.

The general pattern for your situation is to specify a callback method which takes an action as a final parameter.
The simplest way to implement the action is to take a single parameter which is the webresponse object. To aid code reuse and separation of concerns you'll probably want to move to having the action take a tuple of an Exception or the raw (or possibly formatted) response content.

You'll want to write your method something like:

```
private string request(string json,
                       string url,
                       Action<Exception, string> callback)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => 
        {
            // add better error handling than this!!!
            try
            {
                callback(e.Error, e.Result);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                callback(exc, null);
            }
        };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url);    
}
```

Alternativey, you could use the async ctp http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360

Answer (score -2):

This sychronous method can be used, but it will block your thread until the download is completed and is therefore not the preferred method, but I think it will answer your question:

```
private string Request(string url) 
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    return client.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
}
```

Comment: There is no synchronous method `DownloadString` in WP7 `WebClient`... Calling a async method in a synchronous way is not that easy...